# How to get a group header to appear before the group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that is grouped by Team Name.  When I run it, I get this:

```
Team1   |  Person1  |  Unit1  |  Hours1
        |  Person2  |  Unit2  |  Hours2
        |  Person3  |  Unit3  |  Hours3
Team2   |  Person4  |  Unit4  |  Hours4
        |  Person5  |  Unit5  |  Hours5
```

But what I want is this:

```
Team1
Person1  |  Unit1  |  Hours1
Person2  |  Unit2  |  Hours2
Person3  |  Unit3  |  Hours3
Team2
Person4  |  Unit4  |  Hours4
Person5  |  Unit5  |  Hours5
```

I'm not sure how to get this look.  Is there a simple guide for dummies out there that might help me in my quest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pretty much got everything in place - just need a few changes here.

It looks like the tablix is grouped on `Team` fine, so you need to remove the summary column and add a group header row.

I expect the current tablix looks like:

[image]

To get your result, delete the summary column:

[image]

Then add a total through the Details group drop down:

[image]

Now you have a group header row. Add `Team` as required:

[image]

Now it looks like your requirements!

[image]